# Using cloud functions vs cloud run as webhook for dialogflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, webhooks, google-cloud-run

I don't know much about web development and cloud computing. From what I've read when using Cloud functions as the webhook service for dialogflow, you are limited to write code in just 1 source file. I would like to create a real complex dialogflow agent, so It would be handy to have an organized code structure to make the development easier.
I've recently discovered Cloud run which seems like it can also handle webhook requests and makes it possible to develop a complex code structure.

I don't want to use Cloud Run just because it is inconvenient to write everything in one file, but on the other hand it would be strange to have a cloud function with a single file with thousands of lines of code.

Is it possible to have multiple files in a single cloud function?
Is cloud run suitable for my problem? (create a complex dialogflow agent)

Comment: Yes, it's possible to deploy multiple source files for one function.  I'm not sure why you're thinking it's not possible.

Comment: That's because I looked at the already created cloud function by dialogflow... It has inline editor option enabled, which limits it to just 1 source file.
I guess the alternative is to use CloudSource repository right? Thank you!

Comment: You have lots of options.  You can also deploy with the Firebase CLI, or gcloud.  There is lots of documentation on how to work with Cloud Functions as an independent product.

Comment: FYI: I think you are worrying about the wrong things. A source file with a thousand lines is very common in projects with a few hundred thousand lines of code. Editors today can handle just about anything, including collapsing code. Start with the basics and worry about nuances later, after you understand them.

Answer (score 1):

**Is it possible to have multiple files in a single cloud function?**

Yes. When you [deploy to Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying) you create a bundle with all your source files or have it pull from a source repository.

**But Dialogflow only allows `index.js` and `package.json` in the Built-In Editor**

For simplicity, the built-in code editor only allows you to edit those two files. But the built-in editor is mostly just meant for basic testing. If you're doing serious coding, you probably already have an environment you prefer to use to code and deploy that code.

**Is Cloud Run suitable?**

Certainly. The biggest thing Cloud Run will get you is complete control over your runtime environment, since you're specifying the details of that environment in addition to the code.

The biggest downside, however, is that you also have to determine details of that environment. Cloud Funcitons provide an HTTPS server without you having to worry about those details, as long as the rest of the environment is suitable.

**What other options do I have?**

Anywhere you want! Dialogflow only requires that your webhook

- Be at a public address (ie - one that Google can resolve and reach)
- Runs an HTTPS server at that address with a non-self-signed certificate

During testing, it is common to run it on your own machine via a tunnel such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com), but this isn't a good idea in production. If you're already familiar with running an HTTPS server in another environment, and you wish to continue using that environment, you should be fine.